# How to merge two tables in postgresql based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables namely `A` and `B`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
    personid VARCHAR(10),
    writers VARCHAR(500),
    job VARCHAR(300)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    personid VARCHAR(10),
    writers VARCHAR(500),
    job VARCHAR(300)
);
```

They have following entries:

```sql
INSERT INTO A (personid,role,job) VALUES('tt100123', 'writer', 'play')
INSERT INTO B (personid,role,job) VALUES('tt100123', 'writer', '')
INSERT INTO B (personid,role,job) VALUES('tt100124', 'writer', null)
```

I have to merge these two tables such that table `A` has all entries from table `B` where `personid` and `writer` as unique and also that `job` value from table `A` is taken instead of that of table `B`. For example, select query on `A` should return following entries:

```
tt100123,writer,play
tt100124,writer,null
```

Notice that entry from table `B` where `personid` is `tt100123` and `role` is `writer` and job as `` is not merged to table `A`.

I tried union of these two tables but that doesn't return what I desire:

```sql
SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B
```

```
tt100123,writer 
tt100123,writer,play
tt100124,writer,null
```

Could someone please suggest how could this be achieved? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows from `A` and then non-matching rows from `B`:

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.personid = b.personid and a.role = b.role);
```

Note:  It is unclear what the second column is actually called.

Comment: Second column is called `role`. What does `select 1` means here?

Comment: @iamsmkr . . . `not exists` just checks if any row is returned.  The columns on that row are immaterial and `1` is simple to type.

Comment: `union` seems to give similar results. Is there any advantage of using `union all` over `union`?? @gordon-linoff

Comment: @iamsmkr . . . Absolutely.  `union` incurs additional overhead to remove duplicate values.